# Singleton in rails immutable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an instance of singleton class `SingletonClass` within module `Modulename`

```
Modulename::SingletonClass.instance
```

which has a hash `@hashname`. I have a method on `SingletonClass` that adds new keys to `@hashname`.

When I add a new key to `@hashname`, I can see the new key exists by doing `puts @hashname` in the controller, but when I do it in `SingletonClass`, it seems that the new key is not added. Why is that? Why am I able to see the change in the `@hashname` from controller but not from the singleton class?

Here is a code that reproduces the behaviour I'm trying to describe :

```
module MyModule
    module SubModule

        class SingletonClass

            include Singleton

            def initialize

                @items = {}
                @items = MyMode.all.map{|c| {c.name => c.secondary_name}}.reduce(:merge)

            end

            def add_new_item(name, secondary_name)
                @items[name] = secondary_name
            end

            def do_something
                @items.each do |k,v|
                    ap "#{k} => #{v}"
                end
            end

                    def another_method
                       do_something
                    end

        end
    end
end
```

When I do this from my controller :

```
singleton = MyModule::SubModule::SingletonClass.instance
singleton.add_new_item('test', 'test1')
```

Then this also from controller :

```
singleton.do_something
```

The new item gets printed out so its good.

But when I invoke `another_method` from my within my singleton class, the new item appears not to be added

Comment: we'll need to see your code for the class. can you create a small class that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: Is your do_something being invoked from a separate controller action?

Comment: Is this in development mode? What file path is `MyModule::SubModule::SingletonClass` sitting in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked fine for me when `MyMode.all` returned values. But when it was an empty array, then `@items =` became nil.

that happens because:

```
[].reduce(:merge)
=> nil
```

Easiest way to fix is probably:

```
@items = {}
people = MyMode.all.map{|c| {c.name => c.secondary_name}}.reduce(:merge)
@items = people if people
```

Comment: thanks for your response. `people` in your example is never nil in my case. And the case works for me when I reproduce it in rails console but not in my app

Comment: Maybe it's as simple as you not calling it via "MyModule::SubModule::SingletonClass.instance.add_new_item(rand(), 'test1')" ?

Comment: My issue that this module was included in Job which was run by other process rather than webserver so the changes haven't been updated by worker. thanks